# Data sorting in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sorting, code-first

I am really new to ASP.net MVC.In my project I have 2 models. Person.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace CleryAct.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public string rockets { get; set; }
        public bool csa { get; set; }
        public string fname { get; set; }
        public string lname { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Session.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace CleryAct.Models
{
    public class Session
    {

        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string rockets { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
        public DateTime training { get; set; }


    }
}
```

I also have 1 view folder with a Details and Index view inside. I created this by adding a new scaffolding item under controller and linking it to my Person Model. In my details folder I an trying to sort the list of dates that comes up. I can not figure out how to call on the dates in my sort function. Persons controller Details .cs

```
public ActionResult Details(string id, string sortOrder)
{
    ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
    ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
    if (person == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    var persons = from s in db.Persons select s;

    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        default:
            persons = persons.OrderBy(s => s.Sessions);
            break;
        case "date_desc":
            persons = persons.OrderByDescending(s => s.Sessions);
            break;
    }
    return View(person);
}
```

Details view code

```html
<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
  <h4>Person</h4>
  <hr />
  <dl class="dl-horizontal">

    <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.lname), @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fname) 
        </dt>

    <dd>
      @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.lname), @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.fname)
    </dd>

    <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.rockets)
        </dt>

    <dd>
      @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.rockets)
    </dd>

    <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.email)
        </dt>

    <dd>
      @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.email)
    </dd>
    <br />
    <br />
    <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Sessions)
        </dt>
    <dd>
      <table class="table">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Sessions) {
        <tr>
          <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.training)
          </td>
        </tr>
        }
      </table>
    </dd>

  </dl>
</div>
<p>
  @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.rockets }) | @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

Comment: So you want to take a `Person` along with `Sessions` sorted by `training`, right?

Comment: Inside of my persons view they my click on a button that lists more details about the person. In the area I relisted their name and have a list of all their previous training sessions. I want those training sessions to be sorted by date. The training sessions comes from the Sessions model though so I can not figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
public ActionResult Details(string id, string sortOrder)
{
    // don't know what logic stands behind these ViewBag usages.
    // maybe you should get rid of them
    ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
    ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    // changes start
    Person person = db.Persons.Include(x => x.Sessions).FirstOrDefault(p => p.rockets == id);
    if (person == null)
        return HttpNotFound();
    person.Sessions = sortOrder == "date_desc" ? 
        person.Sessions.OrderByDescending(s => s.training).ToList() : 
        person.Sessions.OrderBy(s => s.training).ToList();
    // changes end
    return View(person);
}
```

You must be missing `id` field on `Person` class. Also why not to use `int id` instead of `string id` in action? You have integer `id` in `Session` - `public int ID { get; set; }`.

Comment: The find is erroring out 
Error 3 'System.Linq.IQueryable<CleryAct.Models.Person>' does not contain a definition for 'Find' and no extension method 'Find' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<CleryAct.Models.Person>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) I do have using System.Collections.Generic included in the project

Comment: @netgen, check out edit. IT should be `FirstOrDefault` instead. Also where is your `ID` field on `Person`?

Comment: @netgen, is `rockets` indeed a key column?

Comment: It worked. Also rockets is supposed to be the key. I am building it for a system that has a unique "rocket number" assigned to each person already. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
case "date_desc":
  persons = persons.OrderByDescending(s => s.Sessions.Select(t => t.training));
  break;
```

The .Select() will create a collection of the training dates from the Sessions for you to order.

Answer (score 0):

You just need this:

```
switch (sortOrder)
{
    case "date_desc":
        person.Sessions = person.Sessions
                                .OrderByDescending(session => session.Training);
        break;
    default:
        person.Sessions = person.Sessions
                                .OrderBy(session => session.Training);
        break;

}
```

There isn't any reason for fetching all the `persons` and then ordering them based on sessions. It doesn't make sense. The only thing you need is just to order the Sessions of a person.